# warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference - At least one of the arguments cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I am working in Windows 8.1(64bit), VS 2013. I am building a project which is showing a warning like this.
My project is working fine but anyway i need to remove this warning. Please help

> warning MSB3305: Processing COM reference "NETCONLib" from path
> "C:\Windows\system32\hnetcfg.dll". At least one of the arguments for
> 'INetConnection.GetProperties' cannot be marshaled by the runtime
> marshaler.Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may
> require unsafe code to manipulate

Please help in solving this warning..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9):

IanG [found a solution](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7a7c352b-20cb-4931-b3b5-27e899016f75/turning-off-msbuild-warnings-msb3305?forum=msbuild) which did work for me, too:

> I've added this in the PropertyGroup at the top of my .csproj file:
>
> ```
> <ResolveComReferenceSilent>True</ResolveComReferenceSilent>
> ```

Keep in mind, that this will silence any warnings. If you happen to use features which are not meant to be used from managed code, then don't use this "solution".

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that your project is working fine and you want to remove warning message only,
You can do it by using `#pragma warning`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/2c8f766e.aspx

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply: I tried that one... That will work fine but is there any other way to remove this kind of warnings. I mean any changes in settings or something like that.. Hoping for a reply..

Comment: Hi, actually I don't have any experience about `NETCONLib`. I just thought you want to remove the warning messages only.

Comment: Howerver, I searched some code related with `NETCONLib`, I found [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917304/how-do-i-detect-a-disabled-network-interface-connection-from-a-windows-applicati). And when I built the sample code, I didn't any warning message. My build is 'vs2010/win32' on WIN7.
I've used `INetConnection::GetProperties()` function also. I'm sorry but I think I couldn't help more

Comment: Hi.. No issues. I tried his, but not working as expected.. Finally am forced to supress warning using #pragma.. Thanks for the support

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm sorry about that. But, I think if your program is working well regardless of the MSBxxx warning, just removing the warning can be a good method.